# Rename the columns of a data frame with its 1st row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I rename the columns of a data frame with its 1st row using a dplyr chain?

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(a=c("b","c"),d=c("e","f"))
colnames(df)<-df[1,])           #normal renaming (1st row used to set column names)


df<-data.frame(a=c("b","c"),d=c("e","f"))
df<- df%>%rename(????)   #dplyr chain renaming
```

Comment: It is better to use the normal renaming

Comment: You could use `stats::setNames()` or `purrr::set_names()` (but your data frame has `factor` cols, which makes it a bit harder)